# Firebase Functions "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted."

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, request, google-cloud-functions

Has anyone faced the below error for their firebase functions (and was pretty sure it shouldn't have been even near the [quota of 256 MB](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas))?

> Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

**The Function**

Specifically, it's a tri-weekly CRON-based function that makes **30 Feedly API calls to retrieve metadata (incl. summary/content information) for 100 articles each.** A rough math of how much data is pulled from & pushed to Firebase Database, tells me it shouldn't be near even half the stated limit. It also worked for me when locally testing using "firebase functions:shell".

Here is a minimal version of the code (original around ~130 lines):

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.feedlyPull_A = functions.pubsub.topic('triweekly-tick').onPublish((event) => {
  let ps = [];
  for (var catKey in feedlyList) {
    if (feedlyList.hasOwnProperty(catKey)) {

      let read_match_details = {
        uri: 'http://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user%2FUSER_KEY_HERE%2Fcategory%2F' + feedlyList[catKey].key + '&count=100',
        method: 'GET',\
        headers : {
          "Authorization" : "OAUTH KEY HERE"
        },
        json: true
      };
      ps.push(rp(read_match_details));
    }
  }

  let artPromise = admin.database().ref('Article').once('value');

  return artPromise.then(results_art => {
    let articleObj = results_art.val();

    let skillPromise = admin.database().ref('Skill').once('value');

    return skillPromise.then(results_ski => {
      console.log('Skills Retrieved!');
      let skillList = results_ski.val();

      return Promise.all(ps)
      .then((results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let articles = results[i].items;

          let pathName = feedlyList[i].name;

          if (articles && Object.keys(articles).length > 0) {
            for (var key in articles) {
              // A BUNCH OF KEYWORD PARSING ON ARTICLE SUMMARY/CONTENT HERE and storing in arrays
            }

            if (artList) {
              admin.database().ref('Article/'+pathName).set(artList, (snapshot) => {
                console.log('Processed & Pushed: ' + pathName);
              });
            }
          } else {
            console.log('Failed (No articles found): ' + pathName);
          }
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm very new to cloud computing so I'm kinda lost on where to start... Has anyone been able to resolve/debug an issue like this, or have any suggestions?

I was thinking if there was a way to somehow measure cumulative memory (given I'm understanding what that 256 MB refers to), I'd be able to back-track based on trial-and-error on how to resolve, but no clue how to do that...

Thank you so much!
(this has been delaying launch schedule for a bit, so any help would be immensely appreciated!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the source of your memory limit error, but you should adapt your code as follows, in order to return a promise in your Cloud Functions.

Note that it is not clear what is the value of `artList`. It is probably defined in the part of the code you removed for improving the readability.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.feedlyPull_A = functions.pubsub.topic('triweekly-tick').onPublish((event) => {
  let ps = [];
  for (var catKey in feedlyList) {
    if (feedlyList.hasOwnProperty(catKey)) {

      let read_match_details = {
        uri: 'http://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user%2FUSER_KEY_HERE%2Fcategory%2F' + feedlyList[catKey].key + '&count=100',
        method: 'GET',\
        headers : {
          "Authorization" : "OAUTH KEY HERE"
        },
        json: true
      };
      ps.push(rp(read_match_details));
    }
  }

  let artPromise = admin.database().ref('Article').once('value');

  return artPromise.then(results_art => {
    let articleObj = results_art.val();

    let skillPromise = admin.database().ref('Skill').once('value');

    return skillPromise.then(results_ski => {
      console.log('Skills Retrieved!');
      let skillList = results_ski.val();

      return Promise.all(ps)
      .then((results) => {

        let promises = []; 

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let articles = results[i].items;

          let pathName = feedlyList[i].name;

          if (articles && Object.keys(articles).length > 0) {
            for (var key in articles) {
              // A BUNCH OF KEYWORD PARSING ON ARTICLE SUMMARY/CONTENT HERE and storing in arrays
            }

            if (artList) {
               promises.push(admin.database().ref('Article/'+pathName).set(artList));
            } else {
              console.log('Failed (No articles found): ' + pathName);
            }
          }
        }

        return Promise.all(promises);

      }).catch(err => {

        console.log(err);
        return false;   //Important, see the videos I mention below

      });
    });
  });
});
```

I would also suggest that you look at these two must see videos from the Firebase team, about Cloud Functions and promises: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk.

Comment: Thx @renaud-tarnec! Those videos are also super-helpful.

Made your suggested fix (makes complete sense!), but I'm also wondering if it's okay to put the **.then** after the **Promise.all**, instead of its parent promise (`return SkillPromise.then(...`) , as it shows up in the 3rd [Firebase Promises video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc)? I'm still facing error-related issues, leading me to think that could be it...